# Using the double angle formula in the quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving a physics problem and we are asked to derive a formula for the range (R). The solution gives me this formula:

[image]

Now, the solution works perfectly, they simplify the equation to derive an equation for R as indicated by the textbook. However, I am a bit confused on how they get to the last step.

Let me explain why I am confused:

$$gR^2 - 2V_0^2\sin(θ)\cos(θ)R+2V_0^2\cos^2(θ)y=0$$

$$R^2\biggr(g\biggr) - R\biggr(2V_0^2\sin(θ)\cos(θ)\biggr)+\biggr(2V_0^2\cos^2(θ)y\biggr)=0$$

Meaning

$$a = g$$
$$b = -2V_0^2\sin(θ)\cos(θ) = -V_0^2\sin(2θ)$$
$$c = 2V_0^2\cos^2(θ)y$$

Now to plug them into the quadratic formula:

$$\frac{-b ± \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$\frac{2V_0^2\sin(θ)\cos(θ) ± \sqrt{\biggr(-V_0^2\sin(2θ)\biggr)^2-4g\biggr(2V_0^2\cos^2(θ)y\biggr)}}{2g}$$
Now the part that throws me off is that when I simplify $b^2$ I get this:

$$b^2 = \biggr(2V_0^2\sin(θ)\cos(θ)\biggr)^2 = V_0^4\sin^2(2θ)$$

However, in the solution (displayed in the image above) their $b^2$ is:

$$b^2 = V_0^4\sin^4(2θ)$$

Can anyone explain why?

EDIT:
After that, the author of that image continues to simplify and gets to the solution provided by the textbook:

[image]

Comment: For one thing, you have a typo. $2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin 2\theta$, not $2\sin 2\theta$.

Comment: @MPW fixed thanks for the notice, but it would still be $sin^2(2θ)$ and the solution points it to be $sin^4(2θ)$

Comment: You forgot the $y$ under the square root. For the $4$th power you are right

Comment: @Raffaele I can't be right though, the solution reaches the answer of the textbook. Check my last edit.

Comment: @Pablo I don't want you to believe me, believe Wolfram Alpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5By+%3D%3D+v0+Sin%5Bt%5D+R%2F(v0+Cos%5Bt%5D)+-+1%2F2+g+(R%2F(v0+Cos%5Bt%5D))%5E2,+R%5D

Comment: @Raffaele I need to reach this equation though: $R = \Biggr(1 + \sqrt{1+\frac{2gh}{V_0^2Sin^2θ}}\Biggr)\Biggr(\frac{V_0^2}{2g}\Biggr)$